# How would you get question titles into the game?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation, questions, title

I've noticed that many question titles are enigmatic\cryptic\unrevealing\laconic\unfocused etc...

Question titles are the user's initial interface to the question. They are the user's means to  evaluate if he wants to dive in or not.

Perhaps there's a way to add the question titles into the StackOverflow game? Somehow give users motivation to invest some thought before writing them, edit, improve and correct them.

What would you suggest?

Comment: Which game? Is it a ego-shooter?

Comment: I have no idea what this question is talking about.

Comment: @Ladybug - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47234/if-reputation-werent-called-reputation-what-would-you-call-it/47273#47273

Comment: The two answers below are constructive. I really don't understand the cynicism and bad votes. It seemed to me a valid meta SO question that in the worst case will make people aware of the question title chaos and in the best case may inspire some creativity.

Comment: @Jonathan - actually, your question title was a proof of concept, as enigmatic\cryptic\... It's not obvious on first read that you mean rewarding/voting for the title.

Comment: @Gnoupi - thanks for agreeing with me.
Yes indeed I may be one of those with imperfect question titles. Somehow I'm not sure that's the reason why I'm getting negative votes. Is the contents of the question offensive\written badly\irrelevant to meta SO etc... ?
@Voters - care to explain?

Comment: @Jonathan downvotes have a different function on Meta: They are a sign of disagreement (and upvotes one of agreement). Don't worry: Your suggestion is fine. It's just that x number of people don't think there is need for more motivation.

Comment: - Because it was unclear. And because it sounded like this: http://notarealquestion.appspot.com/

Answer (score 1):

There are three badges that specifically reward editing. Since titles have more exposure than any other text in the system, they are more subject to being edited.

I don't really see the need for *more* incentive in this area.

Comment: That's interesting, anyone happens to have statistics on how much titles are edited vs question text blocks?

Comment: @Jonathan: That information currently isn't publicly available because revision history isn't included in the data dump (unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see something like this working would be if there was a separate set of votes for the title and the body of the post, and that seems tedious and unnecessary. The title and body should be considered as one, and voted on as such.

Even though the phrasing of the title is important as an initial introduction to the problem, the body of the post is just as important *if not more so* because it actually contains the details of the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Somehow give users motivation to invest some thought before writing them, edit, improve and correct them.

In my experience, the motivation comes automatically when you start to understand how SO works: You want to do everything to attract as large an audience for your questions as possible.

Comment: you just described a motivation to write controversial, crowd attracting titles, not best descriptive titles.

Comment: @Jonathan not in my experience. The most crowd attracting title is not the one that will give you the best feedback to your question. The best feedback goes to the question clearly describing what the issue is.